# Snort Installation Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, snort

I am a newbie to Snort and doesnt have proper knowledge on installation and configuration of the same. I am following snort official document to install snort on an Ubuntu instance in AWS EC2. I have installed pre-requisites (DAQ) and flex and bison (because that installing pre-requisite failed because of flex and bison). Now I installed Snort and trying to run configure --enable-sourcefire, it fails with error

```
./configure: line 15558: daq-modules-config: command not found
checking for daq_load_modules in -ldaq_static... no
ERROR!  daq_static library not found, go get it from
http://www.snort.org/.
```

Googled and got some results to execute which daq-modules-config and set the path with the above result. But which daq-modules-config returns nothing. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: What's wrong with `apt install snort`?

Comment: @Sven, do you want me to try apt install snort? I was following this:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org-site/production/document_files/files/000/000/122/original/Snort_2.9.9.x_on_Ubuntu_14-16.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA&Expires=1495519873&Signature=7O6Tv%2F8Hi6EJ9biXH8sctPWANiY%3D

Comment: Yes. Its' available in the repos and **much** easier to install and maintain (compiling it yourself means you have to do this regularly for any update).